# disconnecting issues in wcf clients

Tags: .net, wcf

i have a WCF multiple game service.the clients connect to server and call some methods.
if one client lost connection,how to reconnect to the server?is there any event for connection lost?
how server resume its session and return result of method call that was called before disconnection?
can anyone give me some posts or articles about this issues.
sorry for bad English.
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few different things you can and should do in order to handle issues of this type.

Firstly, you can enable [Reliable Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx).  Reliable sessions are based on the WS-ReliableMessageing protocol and can help mask certain failures in messages and transport.  There are also retry attempts and timeouts defined in the reliable sessions.

On the client side, there is a property that indicates the status of the connection (Created, Connected, Faulted) but may not be faulted until after a call.  That is one possibility to check.  Then you can dump your client and recreate the object to connect again.  You will still need to perform try catch blocks and try to recreate your client on faults.

The other issue of your results being returned even after being disconnected could be solved by making your service [ConcurrencyMode as Reentrant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395214.aspx), or [InstanceMode as Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx).  [Here is a CodePlex artcle on why you would use which combination](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#Reentrant).